# 'module' object is not callable , PyTorch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

Training and Testing data PyTorch

```py
import torch
from torch import nn 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class LinearRegressionModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.weight=nn.parameter(torch.randn(1,dtype=torch.float))
        self.bias=nn.parameter(torch.randn(1,dtype=torch.float))
    def forward(self,x:torch.tensor)->torch.tensor:
        return self.weight*x+self.bias

torch.manual_seed(42)
model_0=LinearRegressionModel()
list(model_0.parameter())
```

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your code

```py
import torch
from torch import nn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class LinearRegressionModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, dtype=torch.float))
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, dtype=torch.float))

    def forward(self, x: torch.tensor) -> torch.tensor:
        return self.weight * x + self.bias

torch.manual_seed(42)
model_0 = LinearRegressionModel()
list(model_0.parameters())
```

First you call `__init__`, not `init`
second `nn.Parameter` not `nn.parameter`